# How do i remove the apache2-default page in ubuntu

Tags: server

I need to remove the apache2-default page so i can add my website in ubuntu server!

wqkb.com is my website. i need to put the index.html page where apache2-default page is

Comment: I'm a tad out of date to dealing with Apache, do you know the default path it's checking at, and then modified the files at that path on the drive with your site's files?  (it might be /var/www/, or /usr/share/html/ or something)

Answer (score 1):

The Apache 2 default page is stored at /var/www/index.html. You can overwrite it and move any resources needed into /var/www/ and voila!